# How to find the area bounded by $y=\ln\left(x\right)$ and $y=e+1-x$, and the $x$ axis?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given $\int \int dxdy$, I want to find the area bounded by $y=\ln\left(x\right)$ and $y=e+1-x$, and the $x$ axis.

I think the limits of integral in $y$ axis are from $y=\ln\left(x\right)$ to $y=e+1-x$ so $\int \limits_{y=\ln\left(x\right)}^{e+1-x}dy\int \:dx$, but I don't know how to find the limits of the integral in $x$ axis since the area bounded by $x$ axis? Please give me a clue to solve this problem.

Comment: I think x limits will be from 0 to infinity. first you integrate with respect to y then it will be a function of x and then integrate with respect to x.

Comment: i've calculated it with the limits of the integral in x axis from $0$ to $\infty $ but leads to the wrong answer man. according to my book, the correct answer is $\frac{3}{2}$, but i don't know how to find the limits of the integrals in x axis @prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is convenient to use inverse representation of the curves,
$x=\mathrm{e}^y,\ x=\mathrm{e}+1-y$:

[image]

$$ \int_0^1 \int_{\mathrm{e}^y}^{\mathrm{e}+1-y} dx dy=\frac{3}{2}$$.

Comment: wow very cool man! thank you so much!

Comment: can you send me the image of the curves to my email, ayimxpma@gmail.com? because your image doesn't show up. thank you so much!

Comment: @alethiologist: image sent (in pdf).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

y = ln(x), y = e+1-x

I would say, can guess the solution x = e, y = 1. Other real solution is not.